# How to find/check current permissions in AWS S3 using cli?

Tags: amazon-s3, permissions, file-permissions

I'm quite happy with the speed of [`aws cli`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html) But can't seem to find a way to find out what the permissions are on a file/folder.

E.g. I do:

```
$ curl http://my.s3.amazonaws.com/deploy/tool1/license.key -o ./license.key
$ cat license.key | sed 's/></>\n</g'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>E4D50F0606FFFD48</RequestId>
<HostId>+xxxyyyaaaa=</HostId>

$
$
```

Now `curl http://my.s3.amazonaws.com/deploy/tool1/tool.sh -o ./tool.sh` works just fine and I can get the `tool.sh`. So I suspect teh permissions on `license.key` to be the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to get the permissions on a file in S3 with the CLI, use the `get-object-acl` command of `s3api` (full documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object-acl.html)

Using your example:

```
$ aws s3api get-object-acl \
    --bucket my \
    --key deploy/tool1/license.key
```